# Is serial correlation affected by random rearrangement of the time series?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, random-generation

Suppose I have coin where P(head on first toss) = P(tail on first toss) = 0.5, and P(head | previous toss was a head) = 0.8 and P(tail | previous toss was a tail) = 0.8.

Suppose I have a given realization of these coin tosses, say H, H, H, H, H, H, T, T, T. It is clear that there is serial correlation, since the first six tosses were heads and the next three tosses were tails. In other words, given that a toss was a head, I can predict whether or not the next toss was a head or tail better than chance.

If I were to randomly rearrange the order of the flips for a given realization, will there still be serial correlation (on average)?

My intuition is that there won't be serial correlation due to the randomness, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

The 'serial correlation' in this case is the chi-square statistics for a table where the rows are previous toss, and columns are next toss outcomes. It is clear that if you shuffle the order of toss outcomes you will expect Head or Tail to land with their respective probabilities p and q, which must be 0.5 in your case. The chi-square test will show no significant dependence between previous and next toss outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so certain. If two tosses were originally separated by $k$ steps, then they are equal if between them the outcome changed 0, 2, 4, 6, ... times and unequal if it changed 1, 3, 5, ... times. The distribution of the number of changes $c$ is binomial with probability 0.2 and $k$ trials. Thus, the chance they are equal is $\sum_{c \in 0, 2, 4, ...} {k \choose c} 0.8^{k-c} 0.2^{c}$. That's not 0.5, usually. What am I missing?